# Why doesn't this set the width of the document?

Tags: jquery, html

Why doesn't this set the width of the document.
I want the left div to be 100px, and the right div to be documentwidth - 100px
Thanks for your time!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stack.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</script>
<button></button>
<div id="parent">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
var $doc_width = $(document).width();
var $rightwidth = $doc_width - 100;
$("#right").width($rightwidth);
});
});


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because there's no closing `</script>` tag in your code? And you have an extra `});` that isn't needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You had a closing script tag after your body tag
2. You didn't have a closing script tag after the script you are trying to run
3. You had an extra set of closing brackets & parentheses that weren't required.

Try this edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stack.css">
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button></button>
<div id="parent">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var $doc_width = $(document).width();
var $rightwidth = $doc_width - 100;
$("#right").width($rightwidth);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does right width have to be a number? Is there a way you can write ($rightwidth px?)

Comment: Is the jquery-1.8.3.js file installed in the root directory on your server?

Comment: according to the way you've declared your script, it's looking for the file "jQuery-1.8.3.js" and expects it to be located in the same place as the html file calling it. I would suggest changing `<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>` to `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` This uses Google's hosted library version instead and points to a direct url.